# DataTables warning (table id = 'example'): Requested unknown parameter 'clientId' from the data source for row 0

Tags: spring, jquery-ui, jquery, datatables

I am unable to resolve the error, I went through all the suggestion given on many sites. Any suggestion would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

jQuery code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var client = {
        "clientId": $('#clientId').val(),
            "firstName": $('#firstName').val(),
            "lastName": null
    };
    var jsonReqString = JSON.stringify(client, function (key, value) {
        if (typeof value == "number") return value;
        if (typeof value == "boolean") return value;
        return value == "" ? null : value;
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "/SimpleDT/search",
        type: "POST",
        data: jsonReqString,
        dataType: "json",
        jsonp: "cspcb",
        contentType: "application/json",
        timeout: 60000,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: false
        },
        beforeSend: function (xhrObj) {},
        success: function (retdata) {
            alert("retdata = " + retdata);
            //retdata ={"aaData": retdata};

            var result_string = JSON.stringify(retdata, function (key, value) {
                if (typeof value == "number") return value;
                if (typeof value == "boolean") return value;
                if (key == 'clientId' && value == "") return "123321";

                return value == "" ? null : value;
            });

            var objs = jQuery.parseJSON(result_string);

            console.log("result_string data=" + result_string);

            console.log("Obj=" + objs);

            var lang = "";
            $.each(objs, function () {
                lang += this['clientId'] + "--" + this['firstName'] + "--" + this['lastName'] + "--" + this['compName'] + "--" + this['fileNo'] + "--" + this['resiAddr1'] + "--" + this['resiAddr2'] + "--" + this['resiAddr3'] + "--" + this['city'] + "--" + this['pinCode'] + "--" + this['mobileNo1'] + "--" + this['mobileNo2'] + "--" + this['mobileNo3'] + "--" + this['submissionDate'] + "--" + this['reminderDate'];
                console.log(lang);
                lang = "";
            });
            $('#example').dataTable({
                /* "bProcessing": true,
                            "bServerSide": true,
                            "sAjaxSource": "/Spring3Hibernate4Annotation/search",
                            "sServerMethod": "POST", 
                                */
                    "aaData": "result_string",
                /*  "aoColumns" : [ {
                                "mDataProp" : "clientId", sDefaultContent: "n/a" 
                            }, {
                                "mDataProp" : "firstName", sDefaultContent: "n/a" 
                            }, {
                                "mDataProp" : "lastName", sDefaultContent: "n/a" 
                            }, {
                                "mDataProp" : "compName", sDefaultContent: "n/a" 
                            }, {
                                "mDataProp" : "fileNo", sDefaultContent: "n/a" 
                            } ] */

                    "aoColumns": [{
                    "mDataProp": "clientId"
                }, {
                    "mDataProp": "firstName"
                }, {
                    "mDataProp": "lastName"
                }, {
                    "mDataProp": "compName"
                }, {
                    "mDataProp": "fileNo"
                }]
            });

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(
                "The following error occured in maintainance Query: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

HTML Code :

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display"
    id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="20%">Client Id</th>
            <th width="25%">First Name</th>
            <th width="25%">Last Name</th>
            <th width="15%">Comp Name</th>
            <th width="15%">File No</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Client Id</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Comp Name</th>
            <th>File No.</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Sample : JSON  resonse I received from spring controller:

```
[{
    "clientId": "12345",
        "firstName": "fgh",
        "lastName": "",
        "compName": null,
        "fileNo": null,
        "resiAddr1": null,
        "resiAddr2": null,
        "resiAddr3": null,
        "city": null,
        "pinCode": null,
        "mobileNo1": null,
        "mobileNo2": null,
        "mobileNo3": null,
        "submissionDate": null,
        "reminderDate": null
}, {
    "clientId": "1234",
        "firstName": "",
        "lastName": "",
        "compName": null,
        "fileNo": null,
        "resiAddr1": null,
        "resiAddr2": null,
        "resiAddr3": null,
        "city": null,
        "pinCode": null,
        "mobileNo1": null,
        "mobileNo2": null,
        "mobileNo3": null,
        "submissionDate": null,
        "reminderDate": null
}, {
    "clientId": "1234765",
        "firstName": "XXXXX",
        "lastName": "sdgg",
        "compName": null,
        "fileNo": null,
        "resiAddr1": null,
        "resiAddr2": null,
        "resiAddr3": null,
        "city": null,
        "pinCode": null,
        "mobileNo1": null,
        "mobileNo2": null,
        "mobileNo3": null,
        "submissionDate": null,
        "reminderDate": null
}, {
    "clientId": "2222222",
        "firstName": "dghdhfjfj",
        "lastName": "gsjdjkvbcb",
        "compName": null,
        "fileNo": null,
        "resiAddr1": null,
        "resiAddr2": null,
        "resiAddr3": null,
        "city": null,
        "pinCode": null,
        "mobileNo1": null,
        "mobileNo2": null,
        "mobileNo3": null,
        "submissionDate": null,
        "reminderDate": null
}, {
    "clientId": "2222222123",
        "firstName": "dghdhfjfj",
        "lastName": "gsjdjkvbcb",
        "compName": null,
        "fileNo": null,
        "resiAddr1": null,
        "resiAddr2": null,
        "resiAddr3": null,
        "city": null,
        "pinCode": null,
        "mobileNo1": null,
        "mobileNo2": null,
        "mobileNo3": null,
        "submissionDate": null,
        "reminderDate": null
}, {
    "clientId": "2312234412",
        "firstName": "fdsffsf",
        "lastName": "fsfggg",
        "compName": null,
        "fileNo": null,
        "resiAddr1": null,
        "resiAddr2": null,
        "resiAddr3": null,
        "city": null,
        "pinCode": null,
        "mobileNo1": null,
        "mobileNo2": null,
        "mobileNo3": null,
        "submissionDate": null,
        "reminderDate": null
}, {
    "clientId": "2313377",
        "firstName": "fdsffsf",
        "lastName": "fsfggg",
        "compName": null,
        "fileNo": null,
        "resiAddr1": null,
        "resiAddr2": null,
        "resiAddr3": null,
        "city": null,
        "pinCode": null,
        "mobileNo1": null,
        "mobileNo2": null,
        "mobileNo3": null,
        "submissionDate": null,
        "reminderDate": null
}, {
    "clientId": "23133772",
        "firstName": "ASDFREW",
        "lastName": "Bandalu",
        "compName": null,
        "fileNo": null,
        "resiAddr1": null,
        "resiAddr2": null,
        "resiAddr3": null,
        "city": null,
        "pinCode": null,
        "mobileNo1": null,
        "mobileNo2": null,
        "mobileNo3": null,
        "submissionDate": null,
        "reminderDate": null
}, {
    "clientId": "23133773",
        "firstName": "SASASAS",
        "lastName": "BDDFFDDDD",
        "compName": null,
        "fileNo": null,
        "resiAddr1": null,
        "resiAddr2": null,
        "resiAddr3": null,
        "city": null,
        "pinCode": null,
        "mobileNo1": null,
        "mobileNo2": null,
        "mobileNo3": null,
        "submissionDate": null,
        "reminderDate": null
}, {
    "clientId": "23133774",
        "firstName": "SDASADDS",
        "lastName": "DFASDFF",
        "compName": null,
        "fileNo": null,
        "resiAddr1": null,
        "resiAddr2": null,
        "resiAddr3": null,
        "city": null,
        "pinCode": null,
        "mobileNo1": null,
        "mobileNo2": null,
        "mobileNo3": null,
        "submissionDate": null,
        "reminderDate": null
}, {
    "clientId": "23133775",
        "firstName": "SDASDADD",
        "lastName": "DSADFFFDD",
        "compName": null,
        "fileNo": null,
        "resiAddr1": null,
        "resiAddr2": null,
        "resiAddr3": null,
        "city": null,
        "pinCode": null,
        "mobileNo1": null,
        "mobileNo2": null,
        "mobileNo3": null,
        "submissionDate": null,
        "reminderDate": null
}, {
    "clientId": "23133776",
        "firstName": "ASSSSS",
        "lastName": "DDDSSSS",
        "compName": null,
        "fileNo": null,
        "resiAddr1": null,
        "resiAddr2": null,
        "resiAddr3": null,
        "city": null,
        "pinCode": null,
        "mobileNo1": null,
        "mobileNo2": null,
        "mobileNo3": null,
        "submissionDate": null,
        "reminderDate": null
}, {
    "clientId": "23133777",
        "firstName": "LKJKLLKK",
        "lastName": "LPSLDFF",
        "compName": null,
        "fileNo": null,
        "resiAddr1": null,
        "resiAddr2": null,
        "resiAddr3": null,
        "city": null,
        "pinCode": null,
        "mobileNo1": null,
        "mobileNo2": null,
        "mobileNo3": null,
        "submissionDate": null,
        "reminderDate": null
}, {
    "clientId": "23133778",
        "firstName": "ASDFREW",
        "lastName": "Bandalu",
        "compName": null,
        "fileNo": null,
        "resiAddr1": null,
        "resiAddr2": null,
        "resiAddr3": null,
        "city": null,
        "pinCode": null,
        "mobileNo1": null,
        "mobileNo2": null,
        "mobileNo3": null,
        "submissionDate": null,
        "reminderDate": null
}, {
    "clientId": "2313389",
        "firstName": "fdsffsf",
        "lastName": "fsfggg",
        "compName": null,
        "fileNo": null,
        "resiAddr1": null,
        "resiAddr2": null,
        "resiAddr3": null,
        "city": null,
        "pinCode": null,
        "mobileNo1": null,
        "mobileNo2": null,
        "mobileNo3": null,
        "submissionDate": null,
        "reminderDate": null
}, {
    "clientId": "2344",
        "firstName": "fdsffsf",
        "lastName": "fsfggg",
        "compName": null,
        "fileNo": null,
        "resiAddr1": null,
        "resiAddr2": null,
        "resiAddr3": null,
        "city": null,
        "pinCode": null,
        "mobileNo1": null,
        "mobileNo2": null,
        "mobileNo3": null,
        "submissionDate": null,
        "reminderDate": null
}, {
    "clientId": "234412",
        "firstName": "fdsffsf",
        "lastName": "fsfggg",
        "compName": null,
        "fileNo": null,
        "resiAddr1": null,
        "resiAddr2": null,
        "resiAddr3": null,
        "city": null,
        "pinCode": null,
        "mobileNo1": null,
        "mobileNo2": null,
        "mobileNo3": null,
        "submissionDate": null,
        "reminderDate": null
}, {
    "clientId": "23441q2",
        "firstName": "fdsffsf",
        "lastName": "fsfggg",
        "compName": null,
        "fileNo": null,
        "resiAddr1": null,
        "resiAddr2": null,
        "resiAddr3": null,
        "city": null,
        "pinCode": null,
        "mobileNo1": null,
        "mobileNo2": null,
        "mobileNo3": null,
        "submissionDate": null,
        "reminderDate": null
}, {
    "clientId": "23456",
        "firstName": "Rajiv",
        "lastName": "Muddas",
        "compName": null,
        "fileNo": null,
        "resiAddr1": null,
        "resiAddr2": null,
        "resiAddr3": null,
        "city": null,
        "pinCode": null,
        "mobileNo1": null,
        "mobileNo2": null,
        "mobileNo3": null,
        "submissionDate": null,
        "reminderDate": null
}, {
    "clientId": "33333333",
        "firstName": "Jhon",
        "lastName": "Muddas",
        "compName": null,
        "fileNo": null,
        "resiAddr1": null,
        "resiAddr2": null,
        "resiAddr3": null,
        "city": null,
        "pinCode": null,
        "mobileNo1": null,
        "mobileNo2": null,
        "mobileNo3": null,
        "submissionDate": null,
        "reminderDate": null
}, {
    "clientId": "3333333333",
        "firstName": "RA",
        "lastName": "Gulit",
        "compName": null,
        "fileNo": null,
        "resiAddr1": null,
        "resiAddr2": null,
        "resiAddr3": null,
        "city": null,
        "pinCode": null,
        "mobileNo1": null,
        "mobileNo2": null,
        "mobileNo3": null,
        "submissionDate": null,
        "reminderDate": null
}, {
    "clientId": "43568",
        "firstName": "AFSF",
        "lastName": "ADFFGGSDF",
        "compName": null,
        "fileNo": null,
        "resiAddr1": null,
        "resiAddr2": null,
        "resiAddr3": null,
        "city": null,
        "pinCode": null,
        "mobileNo1": null,
        "mobileNo2": null,
        "mobileNo3": null,
        "submissionDate": null,
        "reminderDate": null
}, {
    "clientId": "444444444",
        "firstName": "Raju",
        "lastName": "cgdhh",
        "compName": null,
        "fileNo": null,
        "resiAddr1": null,
        "resiAddr2": null,
        "resiAddr3": null,
        "city": null,
        "pinCode": null,
        "mobileNo1": null,
        "mobileNo2": null,
        "mobileNo3": null,
        "submissionDate": null,
        "reminderDate": null
}, {
    "clientId": "55555",
        "firstName": "Jhon",
        "lastName": "Muddas",
        "compName": null,
        "fileNo": null,
        "resiAddr1": null,
        "resiAddr2": null,
        "resiAddr3": null,
        "city": null,
        "pinCode": null,
        "mobileNo1": null,
        "mobileNo2": null,
        "mobileNo3": null,
        "submissionDate": null,
        "reminderDate": null
}]
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to put a `tr` with some `td`s in the body so DataTables knows where to render the output:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I got a similar error also when I had an incorrect number of `th` elements compared to my `td`'s so I presume this is similar.

Comment: I tried your suggested solution but no luck.Table is getting loaded with static json properly its only the json response when I am assigning to table its not loading with error.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting `aaData` to a string `"result_string"` you want to set it to the object `retdata` (atleast that is what it looks like).

```
"aaData": retdata,
```

Also `aaData` is supposed to be an array of an array, however an array of objects may work. Usually `mDataProp` is used when you are using an [`sAjaxSource`](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/objects.html).

If you used `sAjaxSource` you could probably do the following instead of your ajax call

```
$('#example').dataTable({
      "sAjaxSource": "/SimpleDT/search",
      "aoColumns": [{ "mDataProp": "clientId"  }, 
                    { "mDataProp": "firstName" }, 
                    { "mDataProp": "lastName"  }, 
                    { "mDataProp": "compName"  }, 
                    { "mDataProp": "fileNo"    }],
      "fnServerData": function( sUrl, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
        oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
            url: sUrl,
            type: "POST",
            data: jsonReqString,
            dataType: "json",
            jsonp: "cspcb",
            contentType: "application/json",
            timeout: 60000,
            xhrFields: { withCredentials: false }
            cache: false
        });
      }
});
```

Comment: you can set it to `retdata` to get the original JSON or `objs` to get the JSON after the modification on JSON.stringify both seem to work

Comment: HI Danny, I tried your suggested solution but no luck this time data table could not load. Is there any other way I can deal with this issue. IF I try to provide the hardcoded json response what I am receiving from back end to the table its getting loaded and showing the record properly I tried to validate the JSON and its getting validated. there is no problem in response as per my understanding what is wrong not able to identify :(.